# multiple depth "peek definition" in vs code as in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, definition, peek

in visual studio there is an option to keep "peeking definitions" from inside a definition, so you can always keep "entering" to the code depth, but easily can navigate between the "depths".
[multiple depth peek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weGNj.png)

this make editing a code, and navigating very easy.
is there something like that in VScode? really missing that.